# CSS and JS files from AWS/Apache on some networks

Tags: javascript, css, apache, amazon-web-services

I am experiencing some issues with a site not loading CSS/JS files from some networks.

The site is hosted on AWS (WS12, Apache). A dev version of the site is hosted on a Mac Mini (OSX 10.9, Apache) on my network.

http://www.bigreviewtv.com/

http://dev.bigreviewtv.com/

From my network both instances work fine. But some users are reporting problems loading the AWS site from their networks. Yet they can successfully load the dev site. I have confirmed the issues by going to the site and connecting to their networks. When I change my connection to via my iPhone the issues disappear.

Problems seem to be related to loading css and js includes. Css and js files show on the Timeline as latency 105ms, 16150.0 days but never load.

What puzzles me is why there would be a difference based on where you load the site from. My office network is iiNet (works). The HQ office is also iiNet (AWS version has problems). But I can sit in the HQ and connect via my iPhone (Optus network) and problems disappear.

Comment: My current efforts revolve around establishing other web servers on the AWS instance and seeing if the problem persists.

I am trying XAMPP and IIS but not having much luck getting Terascript working with either.

Answer (score 0):

Those sites both work for me where I am. I wonder if it is perhaps a geographically related issue. Maybe some clients just have a high latency connection to your servers?  If so then using Amazon's cloudfront might help.

Since you are already serving up the content from S3, you just need to set up your S3 bucket as a new Cloudfront origin and give it a CNAME. Look under 'Cloudfront' in your AWS Console. Your CNAME could be www.yourdomain.com.  This will improve connectivity worldwide and might fix your specific issue.

Comment: The site content is all in the EBS. I have done the AWS Essentials training but am still cloudy (excuse the pun) on why you wouldn't use the storage included with an instance (400Gb in this case) and would use S3 instead. I guess it's to attach multiple EC2 instances to the same data but that is not the case yet.

But I really need to get to the bottom of this issue rather then work around it. Surely AWS should be a reliable and robust place to host a website.